# How to create drop down list for day month and year

Tags: windows-phone

I am developing windows phone app. I am doing the validation process in it and the user should select his date of birth from 3 different drop down list.
Please tell me how to create drop down list for it..

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="DayOfWeek"> 
<toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="1" Content="1"/> 
<toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="2" Content="2"/> 
<toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="3" Content="3"/> 
<toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="4" Content="4"/> </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Comment: <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="DayOfWeek">
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="1" Content="1"/>
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="2" Content="2"/>
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="3" Content="3"/>
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="4" Content="4"/>
                
            </toolkit:ListPicker>

Comment: but in .cs file DayOfWeek giving error as not found

Comment: C# only...............

Comment: include your code that trigger error, so we can possibly see whats wrong with it and how to fix it

Comment: The name 'DayOfWeek' does not exist in the current context D:\PhoneApp\ReservationPage.xaml.cs

Comment: above error comming when i write DayOfWekk.items.add(1); after initiallizecomponent();

Comment: Get Telerik Rad Controls http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx They have one that is 10000000 times better than anything you will create. All you have to do is drag and drop it onto your page. If you don't want to pay for it then look into http://www.DVlup.com you can get free license there.

Comment: Can we do it by using xaml or c# code??

Comment: Have you tried the DateTimePickers from the [WP Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

A control already exists, look at the DatePicker.
[DatePicker Example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-DatePicker-and-94ef5709)